# Detect android phone via jQuery for a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my html source

```
<body>
 <a class="android">back to home page</a>
</body>
```

how can i use inline js/jquery code to say  if android phone click "back to home page" button  href= "x.com" else href= "z.com"
I want to use inline source js/jquery in my html document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in

`<a class="android" id="android" >back to home page</a>`

```js
let anchor = document.getElementById("android");
if (screen.width <= 640) { 
    anchor.href="link"
 }
else{
    anchor.href="link2"
}
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this code which is similar to your code and got the result:                                                                                            var isAndroid = / Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());  
 if (isAndroid)  
{  

    document.getElementById("abc").href = "link1";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("acb").href = "link2";
}

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var isAndroid = / Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
 
    if (isAndroid) {
      document.getElementById("abc").href = "https://stackoverflow.com/;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("abc").href = "https://link2";
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.